# Crashed while inserting text in edittext

Tags: java, android

I have a popupwindow in which i have edit text.when ever i write some string with @gmail. (On inserting dot it crashesh) into editext the app crashes.for example if i write anil472@gmail.com ,it crashesh. It does not crashes if i simply write @gmail.com or any other string.it only crashes in scenario when we have some string appnended with @ and then appended with dot after some string

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke direct method 'void android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.initDrawables()' on a null object reference
at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.access$300(Editor.java:6696)
at android.widget.Editor.getEmailPopupWindow(Editor.java:1469)
at android.widget.Editor.showEmailPopupWindow(Editor.java:1477)
at android.widget.Editor.handleEmailPopup(Editor.java:1456)
at android.widget.Editor.updateCursorPosition(Editor.java:2099)
at android.widget.TextView.getUpdatedHighlightPath(TextView.java:7823)
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:8008)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21473)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20350)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4396)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4369)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4396)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4369)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4396)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4369)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4396)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4369)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20310)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:575)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:581)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3707)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2839)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1800)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7773)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1058)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:865)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:800)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1043)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: Provide code sample to execute and debug

Comment: Is the edittext initialized?

Comment: @david innocent yes it is initialized

Comment: Provide the code for that single thing.